# Insert Query is Wrong on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i am trying to learn Ruby on Rails and i tried to code simple product creation to database but rails only executes the insert query with only created_at and updated_at values. Here is my products_controller's create action ;

```
def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product_params])

    @product.save
    redirect_to @product
end

private 
    def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:title, :price)
    end
```

Here is my new.html.erb under products folder ;

```
<%= form_with scope: :product ,url:products_path, local: true do |form| %>
<p>
 <%= form.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= form.text_field :price %>
</p>

<p>
<%= form.submit %>
```

<% end %>

And this is the SQL query executed by Rails looking to Rails Server

> Started POST "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-04 16:44:52 +0300
>   Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9Z4aFNpMv+uUPXx+LkHoOtYpWae/8tIOCQ3Jt47AFScp/vVHTWI+G4d6CjHqBz6t5L5UR57I7Gh7bUWog1Dqow==", "product"=>{"title"=>"brokoli", "price"=>"3434"}, "commit"=>"Save Product"}
>      (0.2ms)  BEGIN
>     ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:8
>     Product Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `products` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2018-12-04 13:44:52', '2018-12-04 13:44:52')
>     ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:8
>      (5.4ms)  COMMIT
>     ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:8
>   Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products/12
>   Completed 302 Found in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 7.4ms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do

```
@product = Product.new(params[:product_params])
```

You do

```
@product = Product.new(product_params)
```

The `product_params` is a method that returns the white-listed params entries.

Answer (score 0):

def create
 @product = Product.new(product_params) @product.save 
redirect_to @product 
end 
private 
def product_params params.require(:product).permit(:title, :price)
 end